# Deny users access to site home, allow access to document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, security

I am using SharePoint Foundation 2010 and working on managing permissions at the moment. I would like all users to have access to the document library "Shared Documents". I would like only users part of the AD groups "Admin" and "Doc Admin" to see anything else on the site. If the user is not part of those two groups and tried to go directly to the SharePoint site I would like an access denied error. But, it they go directly to the document library, they should have access.

I have two groups, for complexity lets call them Group A and Group B. Every user in AD is part of Group A or Group B (This includes the Admin and Doc Admin groups who should be able to access the site directly)

I tried to make a change to the user policy regarding those 4 groups but it doesn't seem to be cooperating.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up user policy on web application is not proper way how to fulfill your requirements.

You should set permissions on the site for groups GroupA and GroupB. Then break permission inheritance on Shared Documents. Remove permissions for GroupA and GroupB and set permissions for Admin and Doc Admin groups. Beware how SharePoint handles access check. Members of Admin group or Doc Admin group will have access to Shared Documents library. There's no way how to define that only users that are members of Admin and Doc Admin have access to Shared Documents library.

Comment: It's the other way around.  Set permissions on site to allow for the Admin/Doc Admin groups, then break inheritance, and add the Group A/B to the library.